# Azure functions - Binding list is empty

Tags: azure, azure-functions

After creating a new azure function, my list of bindings is empty. I go to integrate, try to add an input or output binding, list is empty. 
I modify func.json to manually add the binding, is also not working.
Probably is related to templates, but I did not found the right solution. 
I created the function with.net and linux configuration, all other as defaults. When I go to the integrate menu, input and output bindings lists are empty
Thanks for the help

**Update:**
I could not fix the issue, after creating my third function, this third function now contains the full list of expected bindings. I was unable to fix the original functions

Comment: Can you explain how created the function and which options you chose?  There isn't enough information here to reproduce.